# Is there any way to show, or throw, a PHP warning?

Tags: php, warnings

I have a `select()` method in a database class, that has an optional boolean argument `$sum`. This argument is used to say if the method should use `COUNT(*)` or not too.

I would like to show a warning, like those normal PHP errors, if I try to access `$class->sum` if the attribute is not set (i.e. when I call `select()` with `$sum == false`.

Is there any way to show a warning like this, or I should just echo an error and be happy?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

If you want to generate a warning, you should write

```
trigger_error($yourErrorMessage, E_USER_WARNING);
```

[`trigger_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) has the `$error_type` parameter for setting the error level (`Notice`, `Warning` or `Fatal error`). The constants are, respectively:

```
E_USER_NOTICE             // Notice (default)
E_USER_WARNING            // Warning
E_USER_ERROR              // Fatal Error
```

---

Note that `Fatal error` stops the execution of subsequent PHP code, while `Notice` and `Warning` let it continue.

From PHP 5.5, you should also consider the [Finally](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) statement.

Comment: don't forget to **`return ;`** when used in e.g. `__call` or `__callStatic`, it's just a function as any other, it is **not a language construct**. If you don't your function may fail in some further place where it shouldn't go in the first place

Answer (score 15):

You could try [`trigger_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php).

Comment: ... Using E_WARNING as the 2nd argument.

Comment: `trigger_error()` can only accept warnings of the E_USER family; use E_USER_WARNING instead.

Answer (score 7):

You're going the object-oriented approach, so I suggest a look into [exceptions.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: +1 Exceptions will give you the full backtrace information for debugging, whereas trigger_error() will not give you a useful file name / line number.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but an exception for this problem is just so much trouble. It's an easy recoverable non-fatal error, that would happen quickly on developing; triggering an warning is enough to inform the dev about what happened.

Comment: Warnings exist for a reason. You shouldn't just ignore them and continue on your merry way, because something has *most likely* but not necessarily gone wrong. Throwing Exceptions forces the programmer to deal with the error **before the end of the script**. If you just want to inform the dev, an Exception is still a more robust way of doing it because your program won't continue when the state is possibly no longer correct. If you want to continue, you can Try your code, Catch the error and deal with it as appropriate.

Comment: @CJDennis and if I just want to inform that, as example, this page is using a deprecated function which should be converted some day?

Comment: @Zhigalin-ReinstateCMs Only libraries should raise deprecation warnings. Code using deprecated functions ("this page") should not alter deprecation warnings. Deprecated functions still work ... today, so the state will be be correct (barring bugs). They might be removed in the next release of the library. If you see a deprecated function being used in "this page", the responsible thing to do is to refactor your code to use only non-deprecated functions.