# How to get Notice / Warning as object in PHP?

Tags: php, object, warnings, notice

I'm using PHP 7.3. I'm curious if it is possible to get PHP's `Notice` or `Warning` as an **object** (raised by PHP itself and not by user)? I would appreciate any examples including PHP manual references or code snippets from PHP's internals.

**Note:** I'm not asking about `set_error_handler` function which can catch warnings and notices but sadly *not as a full objects* (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). I don't want to generate my own `Notice` / `Warning` objects with `trigger_error` as it mentioned here: [Is there any way to show, or throw, a PHP warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095860/is-there-any-way-to-show-or-throw-a-php-warning).

Comment: @MarkusZeller My goal is to get PHP generated `Notice` / `Warning` as an **object**. Is that posible or not possible? I don't want get User generated `Notice` / `Warning` as an object. That would be obviously way too easy. "For researching purposes" if you really wish more deeper reason.

Comment: Relevant source code files: `zend_errors.h`, `zend_exceptions.c`, `zend_exceptions.h` (directory: `Zend`) - https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/79937420c78054438876713eae756becf956f389/Zend